# L.latLng() created object throws "Invalid LatLng object" when used on setZoomAround()

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Using the documentation example, I'm trying to zoom into an specific point. So I do this:

```
var latlng = L.latLng(50.5, 30.5);
$scope.map.setZoomAround(latlng);
```

`$scope.map` is a valid map object created by `L.map()`.

I get this error:

> Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)
>
> ```
> at o.LatLng (leaflet.js:6)
> at Object.unproject (leaflet.js:6)
> at Object.pointToLatLng (leaflet.js:6)
> at e.unproject (leaflet.js:6)
> at e.layerPointToLatLng (leaflet.js:6)
> at e.containerPointToLatLng (leaflet.js:6)
> at e.setZoomAround (leaflet.js:6)
> ```

Doing `$scope.map.setZoomAround([50.5, 30.5])`  throws the same error and `$scope.map.setZoomAround(50.5, 30.5)` throws:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check the [parameters for the `setZoomAround` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-setzoomaround), as it expects a zoom level to be specified.

Comment: Oh! you are right. I really didn't notice that error of mine.